# How to filter Results to display correctly

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of movies in a Database.

```
type Database = [Film]
type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Year = Int
type Period = (Year, Year)
type Film = (Title, Cast, Year, Fans)
```

What i want to be able to do is find out what movie out of my list.

**Function One**

- Has the most Fans
- Filtered by a particular actors name.

**Function Two**

- Overall top 5 films (By amount of fans)
- Descending order

I currently have two snippets of code that i'm either trying to make work together. Or find a better sollution:

```
inCast :: Actor -> Film -> Bool
inCast givenActor (_, cast, _, _) = any (\actor -> actor == givenActor) cast
```

and

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

bestFilm :: Database -> Film
bestFilm = maximumBy $ comparing (length . fans)
```

Am i going completely the wrong way about this?

Many thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: 
additional code that i have. I can't seem to use it though, to aid me in getting this part solved. 
Any ideas?

```
filmsWithFan :: Fan -> [Film]
filmsWithFan givenFan = filter (isFan givenFan) testDatabase
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? There was a similar one posted yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789061/film-database-in-haskell. If it's homework, please tag it as such. It's also the reason I'm merely giving you hints, rather than the whole answer. It's also what you seem to be asking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are definitely on the right track. Though the last function, `filmsWithFan`, will not help you in this case. I'll give you some hints:

**Function 1:**

Think about the type signature you want to have for your function first:

```
topByFanAndActor :: Actor ->  Database -> Film
topByFanAndActor actor films = undefined
```

Think about how you can combine the two functions you provided, mainly `inCast` and `bestFilm` to achieve that type signature. You will definitely need to use a higher order function that processes lists. If you'll need another hint I can tell what function that would be.

EDIT:

So you need to transform the give list `films` into a list of films the given `actor` stars in. To do that you need to [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afilter) that list using your function `inCast`. Afterwards you need to extract the movie with the maximum number of fans from that list, for that you will use `bestFilm`.

**Function 2:**

In this case the type signature will be quite simple:

```
topFiveDesc :: Database -> Database
```

but you can make it a bit nicer if you make the number of movies return variable:

```
topDesc :: Database -> Int -> Database
topDesc films num = undefined
```

Think about exactly what you have to do with the films now. You need to sort it by a certain criterion (the number of fans). A criterion defined similarly to the one in `bestFilm`. And afterwards you need to take the first `num` films from that list.

Comment: OK, since it looks like homework I will not give you a full answer to both questions. Choose the one on which you'd like me to elaborate and I'm sure you'll get the other one after that.

Comment: Ok, I edited it. Take a look now and see if that helps.

Comment: I added a link to `filter` in case you're struggling with that.